# Node.js: Replace a second part of a pattern in a text file line-by-line

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I've a less file with content like this:

```
@background: #345602;
@imgBack: #000;
```

I can read the whole text file into a variable, and latter save the content of the variable modifying the file:

```
var lessStr = grunt.file.read('./myLessFile.less');
```

Now I want to change the variable, say, `@imgBack` to `#ff0000`. So that, the modified file would look like:

```
@background: #345602;
@imgBack: #ff0000;
```

I there any way to do this by regular expression match and replace? Please help.

**EDIT**

I've code like:

```
var str = '@black:                 #000;\n@grayDarker:            #222;\n@grayDark:              #333;\n@gray:                  #555;\n@grayLight:             #999;';
var varName = '@black';
var replace = '#ab4564';
var regex = '(' + varName + ':\\s*)(?:#[a-z0-9]+)(.*)$';
var re = new RegExp(regex, 'm');
var replaceStr = '$1' + replace;
str.replace(re, replaceStr);
console.log(str);
```

But it's not working. Have I mistaken something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this,

```
> var str = "@background: #345602;\n@imgBack: #000;";
> str.replace(/^(@imgBack:\s*#).*$/gm, "$1ff0000;");
'@background: #345602;\n@imgBack: #ff0000;'
```

Update:

```
> var str = '@black:                 #000;\n@grayDarker:            #222;\n@grayDark:              #333;\n@gray:                  #555;\n@grayLight:             #999;';
undefined
> var varName = '@black';
> var regex = '(' + varName + ':\\s*)(?:#[a-z0-9]+)(.*)$';
undefined
> var re = new RegExp(regex, 'm');
> var replace = '#ab4564';
undefined
> var replaceStr = "$1" + replace;
undefined
> str.replace(re, replaceStr);
'@black:                 #ab4564\n@grayDarker:            #222;\n@grayDark:              #333;\n@gray:                  #555;\n@grayLight:             #999;'
```

Comment: I get the modified less variable name like, `@background` from a variable. Is there any way to replace this?

Comment: I've added a few more details in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'd mistaken that replace method would replace within the original string. It actually returns a new string.

Answer (score 0):

```
(@imgBack:\s*#)(?:\d+)(.*)$
```

You can use this.Replacement string will be.

`$1#ff0000$2`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iO1uK1/6

Comment: @M42 I've added few more details in the question.